# распределения контента по странам

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, нужно отделить ленту новостей для стран СНГ от общей. То есть, если пользователь зашел на сайт из СНГ, выводим одну ленту, если из Европы/Америки - другую (англоязычную). Для этого всё готово, осталось только создать масссив языков (первые 2 символа `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']`), которые входят в эти страны, пока что есть только `ru` и `ua`. Подскажите все остальные заголовки языков стран СНГ?

Comment: Вам не массив языков нужен, а ip с разделением по странам.

Comment: @visman к сожалению нет, нужны именно языки, потому что эти языки используются ещё для других нужд, IP не подойдет

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2 https://habrahabr.ru/post/159129/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038236/using-the-php-http-accept-language-server-variable

Answer (score 0):

На языки нельзя ориентироваться, во многих браузерах в СНГ стоит язык EN. Относительно достоверно можно определить только по ip для этого используйте базу geoip. Но такой вариант не учтёт тех, кто заходит через VPN например
Список сокращений стран https://www.artlebedev.ru/country-list/